# How to set chef node attributes using command output in chef recipes

Tags: chef-infra

I am able to fetch the package version and store it in node.run_state['installed_pkg_version'] and puts is displaying the expected value but when i access the same attribute outside the ruby block its empty so can somebody suggest where am i going wrong ??

```
ruby_block "get installed package version" do
    block do
        Chef::Resource::RubyBlock.send(:include, Chef::Mixin::ShellOut)
        command = "/opt/<packagename>/package version | cut -d\"+\" -f1"
        command_out = shell_out(command)
        node.run_state['installed_pkg_version'] = command_out.stdout
        puts("#{node.run_state['installed_pkg_version']}")
    end
    action :create
end
```

chef-client i am running on is 14.14.29

Comment: I think you probably access it before the ruby block is run. Search for `compile` and `converge` stages of the chef client run. https://docs.chef.io/chef_client_overview/

Comment: I am accessing the attribute after the ruby_block step.

Comment: Yes, but the block is not run yet, when you access the node run state. As I said, make sure understand the `compile` and `converge` stages of the chef run. There are a lot of similar questions on SO.

Comment: Anyway I solved the problem by changing the code logic itself itself instead of using/creating the variables.